# how to roslaunch shadow_hand success in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I send "roslaunch sr_hand rviz_muscle.launch", it show config file does not exist:/root/.rviz/display_config does not exist! . And Global Status show error in Rviz.

20130108:Then I do something according your answer.

1..Global Status:Error
Fixed Frame     Fixed Framed[/map]does not exist

Target Frame    OK

2.Download the rviz_motor.vcg from sr_hand/Tutorials/Getting, and then replace the /root/.rviz/display_config  with it.

Run: roslaunch sr_hand rviz_muscle.launch

Error is the same 1., and no hand show.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51595/how-to-roslaunch-shadow_hand-success-in-rviz/) by [batman](https://answers.ros.org/users/3914/batman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the message regarding the displayconfig is because you use rviz the first time. When you close it it asks you id rviz should save the config. After that it shouldn't display any failures.

regarding to the global status error. please post the exact error message (it will show more nfomation when you click on it). Most likely its because the frame id is still not correct. please have a look at that

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0